# How to compile ES2018 javascript dependency?

Tags: clojurescript

I have a project with some NPM deps, noteably `"@grafana/data": "7.0.1"`. These dependencies bring in several other libs like apache-arrow. When I try to require deps via `(require '"@grafana/data")`, I get a bunch of compiler errors like:

```
ERROR: JSC_LANGUAGE_FEATURE. This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT8 mode or better: async function.
```

I found similar kinds of errors addressed in [google closure compiler issues](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/2602) which leads me to beleive that I cant have library dependencies that require modern javascript as the closure compiler can't handle them. Similarly the [closurescript docs](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#language-in-and-language-out) don't allow for a `:language-in` argument for `es-2018` et. al.

The the clojure build.edn settings I set are:

```
 :language-in :es-next
 :language-out :es5
 :rewrite-polyfills
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Is there any way that I can get the closure compiler to handle modern javascript dependencies? Are there some crazy hacks that I can do to make this work?